Inconsistent layout with custom markdown builders
I have the following three builders to provide subscripts and superscripts, plus a dynamically colorable code block. All of them are handled by their respective InlineSyntax handlers properly.
class SuperscriptBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  @override
  Widget visitElementAfter(element, preferredStyle) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: const Offset(0, -5),
      child: Text(element.textContent, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9)),
    );
  }
}

class SubscriptBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  @override
  Widget visitElementAfter(element, preferredStyle) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: const Offset(0, 5),
      child: Text(element.textContent, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9)),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  @override
  Widget visitElementAfter(element, preferredStyle) {
    var (background, color) = switch (element.attributes['color']) {
      // ...
      _ => (Colors.transparent, Colors.black),
    };

    return Container(
      color: background,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
      child: Text(element.textContent, style: TextStyle(color: color)),
    );
  }
}

While all three work as far as display is concerned, they sometimes (without apparent rhyme or reason) disrupt the layout of the text flow, with an extra new line appearing sometimes before, sometimes after the item. Is my approach wrong and should it be changed somehow to work better with the layout inside the Markdown widget?
(Note: the indices are intentionally handled manually, the font in question doesn't support the appropriate Open Type features, this isn't the point, actually.)
